# Multiple Commutative Diagrams

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I need to make two commutative diagrams (I am using the CD environment) in the same line (I mean not one above the other) can anyone give me an idea?

Answer (score 6):

Just place them in the same `equation(*)` environment, perhaps separated by a space (`\quad` or `\qquad`):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{CD}
    a @>>> b \\
    @VVV @AAA \\
    c @= d
  \end{CD}
  \qquad
  \begin{CD}
    x @>>\alpha> y \\
    @VV\kappa V @A\beta AA \\
    v @<\gamma<< w
  \end{CD}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, my solution was make invisible arrows... not to traditional, but i will try your answer.

Comment: @Dimitri Is your question answered by this post? If not, please edit your question. If yes, please accept this answer here by clicking the check mark to its left and I will delete my comment here. Thank you.